# Which is the main clause in "If she beats him he will claim she cheated."

Tags: clauses

> If she beats him he will claim she cheated.

1. she beats him
2. he will claim
3. she cheated

In these clauses which is the main clause of speaker?

Comment: What do you think and why?

Comment: None of those is a main clause! Neither 1) nor 2) nor 3).

Answer (score 2):

If she beats him, he will claim she cheated.

This is a conditional 1 sentence, in which "he will claim she cheated" is a main clause, whereas "if she beats him" is a subordinate clause.

He will claim and she cheated are parts of the main clause.

Answer (score 2):

If she beats him he will claim she cheated.

"He will claim she cheated" is the main clause.

"(That) she cheated" is a noun clause and it's acting as the object of the verb "claim" in the main clause.

"If she beats him" is the conditional clause.

He will claim

What he will claim: she cheated

In what condition: if she beats him

You see, the other clauses are all about "he will claim she cheated" so this is your main clause:-))

P.S. I should thank Araucaria for helping me to improve the answer.:-))